# What's a better translation of this YouTube comment?

Tags: английский

On [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/SLjnLiuh2vs) someone posted the comment

> Интересно, куда же всё-таки пропадает дар речи после песен ДИМАША? Наверное этот дар пропадает вместе с мозгами, потому, что люди несут такую ахинею, что ни в одни ворота не лезет.

which Google Translate turns into

> I wonder where the gift of speech disappears after the songs of DIMASH? Probably this gift disappears along with the brains, because people carry such nonsense that they don’t climb into any gate.

which sounds questionable.  Can you provide a better translation?

Comment: What exactly are you wondering about or doubting?

Comment: It doesn't sound questionable, it's totally nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

The translation overall is OK except for the two idiomatic expression in the end:

1. *"что люди несут такую ахинею"*

It's not "carrying" nonsense, it's "talking nonsense". Though Russians say "carry" they don't actually mean "to carry".

2. *"что ни в одни ворота не лезет"*

First of all, it doesn't relate to the word/object "people" earlier, it relates to the word "nonsense".

You can probably translate it even literally but instead of "climb" I'd instead use something like "squeeze/get through", so it would be:

*"because people are talking such nonsense that it doesn't get through any gates"* which sounds quite awkward, so let's translate it to something the natives will find appropriate:

*"because people are talking complete nonsense"*

Yes, the part about "gates" is used to underscore their nonsensical speech.

In the end:

*"I wonder how people lose the ability to communicate after listening to the songs of DIMASH. Probably the ability disappears along with the brains, because people are talking complete nonsense."*